# Please explain to me how map works in this case

Tags: perl

After `split`, I get an `@digits` array with values of  `1 2 4 8 16 32 64`. However, I cannot understand the mechanism of its processing in the block `if ($digits [-1] == 4) {}`. After which, only `4 6 4` values remain in the same array. Yes, I see that this code works correctly, but how are unnecessary values remove from the array without processing an it?

```
my @input_numbers = qw(1 2 4 8 16 32 64);

my @result = map {
    my @digits = split //, $_;
    if ($digits[-1] == 4) {
        @digits;
    } else {
        (  );
    }
} @input_numbers;

print join(" ", @result); # 4 6 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here. `map` evaluates its code in list context.

Second, a block returns its last evaluated expression.

In your `map`, the last evaluated expression comes from either the `if` or `else` blocks because there are no other statements past that structure. If the `if` case, it returns `@digits`, which adds one or more new items to `map`'s output list.

In the `else` case, the last evaluated expression is `( )`, which is the empty list. This adds no new elements to the output list, thus "excluding" the results from that particular input element.

I'd probably write this task as a list pipeline. The `grep` selects the elements that we know we want to process, then the `map` processes everything it gets:

```
my @result = map { split // } grep { /4\z/ } @input_numbers;
```

Answer (score 4):

A [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) works by taking one element of its input list at a time, running the code in the block with that element in `$_`, and returning whatever the last evaluated statement (which returns) does. These returned values, after processing all elements of the input list, comprise its output list.

So the `@digits` in your block is at every iteration assigned (strings with) the digits of the currently processed element, not all digits of all elements.<sup>†</sup>  They are then either returned in a list, or an empty list is returned which thus "disappears" in the overall return list.<sup>‡</sup>

Since you return the list with these digits from the block when the last one is `4`, then when your `map` block processes `4` (third element in the array) it returns `4`, and when it processes `64` it returns the list with its digits, `6` and `4`. Altogether `4 6 4`.

---

<sup>†</sup>  It may also help realizing that the block in the `map { ... } LIST` syntax stands for a subroutine call with such code executed for every element. This is afforded by use of prototypes.  Note that the prototypes are rightly advised against in casual use but here they are needed.

This cannot be fully implemented in pure Perl, but here is a simple example

```
sub a_bit_like_map :prototype(&$) {
    my ($code, @in) = @_;

    my @res;
    foreach my $el (@in) {
        local $_ = $el;
        push @res, $code->($el);
    }
    return @res
}
```

Now this can be called as either of

```
my @mapped = a_bit_like_map( sub { ... }, LIST );

my @mapped = a_bit_like_map { ... } LIST;
```

This `:prototype` attribute is necessary in newer Perls, and in which signatures are enabled, since without it the syntax would collide with that of signatures.

With older Perls you'll see them used as `sub func(&@) { ... }`.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  A way to use `map` as a filter, too

Comment: Thank you, zdim . Yes, I understand how ```map``` works. And I already use it in my work and I understand how and what it returns. But in this case, I can’t understand how the ```@digits``` array changed in the ```if``` block - after all, there was neither ```shift``` nor ```pop```, what I used to working with arrays.

Comment: @Legioneroff `@digits` doesn't change after it's assigned at the start of the block... Nothing modifies it. It gets a new value for each iteration of the map, just like a variable assigned a value in a sub, though.

Comment: THANKS for everybody! I catch it!

Comment: It's not the "last statement", but the last evaluated statement.

Comment: @briandfoy Well, I don't say "last statement" -- that's why I say "_last statement (which returns)_" .  I guess it's simpler and clearer saying "last evaluated statement," thank you